# Swift Firestore: Getting all data from firestore and inputing data into Table View

Tags: xcode, firebase, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore

**The goal here is to retrieve all the documents of a Firestore Database, then putting the data of those retrieved documents into a Table View.** I'm using Xcode and Firebase.

For example, if I had a Firestore database with this data and documents:

> Document 1
>
> > Name: Bob
> >
> > Email: bob@gmail.com
> >
> > Phone: 408-111-1234
>
> Document 2
>
> > Name: Joe
> >
> > Email: joe@yahoo.com
> >
> > Phone: 408-338-4321

I would like to have  it all in a table view, maybe something like this:

> Bob - bob@gmail.com - 408-111-1234
>
> Joe - joe@yahoo.com - 408-338-4321

So far, I have this set up:

TableViewController:

```
class PeopleViewController: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet var table: UITableView!

var peopleArray = [] as [Array<Any>]
private var document: [DocumentSnapshot] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    table.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    self.table.delegate = self
    self.table.dataSource = self

    loadData()

}
```

And the loadData() func:

```
func loadData() {
        FirebaseFirestore.root.collection("users").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                if let snapshot = snapshot {

                    for document in snapshot.documents {

                        let data = document.data()
                        let name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
                        let email = data["email"] as? String ?? ""
                        let phone = data["phone"] as? String ?? ""
                        let newPerson = ["name": name, "email": email, "phone": phone]
                        self.peopleArray.append(newPerson)
                        print(self.peopleArray)
                    }
                    self.table.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The first thing wrong here is that there is this error:

> Cannot convert value of type '[String : String]' to expected argument type '[Any]'

When I try to append a newPerson in the PeopleArray. I have searched this up, but none of the answers matched this specific error. The second thing is that I have no clue how to even start adding the data from the PeopleArray into the Table View.

I would love some help for both the error and the Table View. Anything is appreciated!

––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

After doing what Vadian recommended, I am stuck with a new error.

> attempt to insert row 2 into section 0, but there are only 1 rows in section 0 after the update

This is the updated func loadData:

```
func loadData() {
    FirebaseFirestore.root.collection("users").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            if let snapshot = snapshot {

                for document in snapshot.documents {
                    self.table.beginUpdates()

                    let data = document.data()
                    let name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
                    let zip = data["zip"] as? String ?? ""
                    let sport = data["sport"] as? String ?? ""
                    let newPerson = Person(name: name, zip: zip, sport: sport)
                    self.people.append(newPerson)

                    let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: self.people.count, section: 0)
                    self.table.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .automatic)
                    self.table.endUpdates()
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.table.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've read about this on another question about how the rows are off by 1, but even when I let indexPath equal to `people.count+1` or `people.count+2`, the error persists. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the syntax

```
var peopleArray = [] as [Array<Any>]
```

is bad practice. If you want to declare an empty array write

```
var peopleArray : [Array<Any>] = []
```

or

```
var peopleArray = [Array<Any>]()
```

---

Second of all your array is a nested array which is not intended. You mean

```
var peopleArray = Array<Any>()
```

which is more descriptive using the alternative syntax

```
var peopleArray = [Any]()
```

---

Third of all as your data is clearly a more specific type than `[Any]` declare the array

```
var peopleArray = [[String:String]]()
```

**This fixes the error**.

---

Fourth of all the recommended data source is a custom struct

```
struct Person {
    let name, email, phone: String
}
```

In this case declare the array (we know that *people* is plural so the suffix *array* is redundant).

```
var people = [Person]()
```

And populate it (you might reload the table view on the main thread)

```
   for document in snapshot.documents {
        let data = document.data()
        let name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
        let email = data["email"] as? String ?? ""
        let phone = data["phone"] as? String ?? ""
        let newPerson = Person(name: name, email: email, phone: phone)
        self.people.append(newPerson)
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.table.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this works and I see what I've been doing wrong. But this only answers half of my question.

Comment: Populating a table view is described in almost all tutorials. For example please read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/CreateATableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH8-SW1) one.

Comment: How would I make a new row for each document when it loads in? I'm searching around but can't seem to spot anything.

Comment: It's described in the tutorial: Add the item to the data source and reload the tableview.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I'm now stuck on another problem. I edited my post and it would be great if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

I researched a lot and fixed the edited part in the question I posted. A simple `-1` in the insert rows fixed the problem.

`let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: self.people.count`**-1**`, section: 0)`

Vadian also helped me with the original problem, which was using

`var peopleArray = [[String:String]]()`

instead of the other incorrect format. I was then able to find how to insert rows by just simply using the `table.insertrows` function.

(I'm just posting this for a simplified answer for anyone else experiencing problems).

Comment: Now you have a lot of redundant code. Delete the lines `beginUpdates()`, `endUpdates()` and the `DispatchQueue.main.async { reloadData() }` block.